# Imported package not available in Jupyter-Python

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, pysftp

#### Importing pysftp into Jupyter Notebook

While importing pysftp into Jupyter Notebook, *ModuleNotFoundError* is shown.

[image: JupyterSnapshot]

---

#### Checking import of pysftp on device?

I have verified the package installation with

> *pip list*   and  *pip show pysftp*

Had imported pysftp package(v0.2.9) and installed it in the below location

> C:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages

[image: pysftp_lib]

**Check : Package installed OKAY**

---

#### Check about package correct path linking from cmd prompt?

I'm using Python 3.7.0 on a WIN machine, verifyed the site package location using

> *import sys* and *sys.path*

image confirms linking of PATH to correct location and the package is successfully executed when python is run through cmd prompt

[image: Python Snapshot]

**Check : Path link and cmd run OKAY**

---

Now could anyone help me solve why the package import in Jupyter Notebook is throwing an error?

Thank you

---

Edit 1: **Check for different environment installed?** added based on one of the answer

[image: Conda Environment]

Only one environment is present in the machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same. I solved by installing directly within Jupyter using the following command:

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install dice-ml
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the notebook through a virtual environment?

You can try running the same commands as you did on CMD by preceding it with `!` as follows:

`!pip list`

Ideally this should list the same contents as shown in CMD. However the results may be different if you are running Jupyter notebook in a virtual environment. If you are unable to see `pysftp`, you need to install it within the virtual environment. This can be done from within your notebook as:

`!pip install pysftp`

Comment: No virtual environment present. Checked for same on anaconda prompt. Updated snapshot in edits of the Qn. Could you now suggest an alternative solution.?  -@anoop

Comment: Could you do a `pip list` within the Anaconda Prompt window as seen in your Edit 1 screenshot (as against the earlier screenshots that were made directly in CMD)?